# Boost converter gets hot

Tags: boost, led-driver, switching-regulator, texas-instruments, buck-boost

I'm building a LCD backlight power supply boosting 5 V to 12 V.
The max current draw from the panel is 12 V 0.4 A.

I am using LMR60214. But the IC is getting hot to touch at full brightness.

I am using 1206 capacitors for input 2.2 uF and output 4.7 uF capacitors.

I used two different inductors for testing
1.10 uH with 3 A IRMS and 7 A saturation current.
2.10 uH with 2.4 A saturation current.

The IC gets hot at full brightness.

If this IC is not suitable for the application, can anyone suggest me an alternate circuitry or  compact switching regulator with more juice without getting hot.

Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

[LMR60214 Datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmr62014.pdf?ts=1695982248331&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLMR62014)

Comment: Post oscillograms of SW pin and inductor current.

Comment: At 500 mohm Rdson and tiny capsule with limited thermal dissipation, it may be just too small for your application.

Comment: Over an amp through a 0.5 ohm resistor in a tiny package is going to get hot.

Comment: 12 V * 0.4 A = 4.8 W. According to the data sheet graphs the circuit will be about 80% efficient, 20% lost in heat, most of it in the IC. 4.8 W * 20% = 0.96 W. That tiny part will get hot.

Answer (score 4):

The theoretical efficiency curve in the datasheet estimates that the efficiency at 5 to 12 volts, 400 mA operation is about 82%. If you calculated how much is the dissipation in this case, the result would be about 1 watt.

The thermal resistance from the silicon chip to the free air is said to be (in the datasheet) so high that 1 W dissipation would cause 265 degrees (centigrade) temperature rise. Obviously some cooling happens also by conducting to the circuit board because your IC still wants to work.

I'm afraid you walk on a tightrope and the operation may well be stopped automatically by the built in thermal shutdown if your operation conditions change a little.

You should either investigate possibilities for better cooling or preferably get a regulator which is not ran so close to the limits.

Comment: Looks like we both had the same observation, at almost the same time.

Comment: I've added a link to TI app notes on thermal stitching for SOT-23 packages, but absolutely no need to remove your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Using [my boost converter tool](http://stades.co.uk/Boost%20converter/Boost%20calculator.html), the peak current is 1.654 amps when the inductor is 2.1 μH. This is at an operating frequency of 1 MHz (a guess on my part): -

[image]

If you look at the image in your question it says the peak current is 1.4 amps: -

[image]

If I change the operating frequency to 1.6 MHz I only just get below the 1.4 amp limit. My web-tool assumes ideal components so, in reality, the peak current is going to be 5 or 10% higher.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the efficiency graph from the front page of the datasheet.

[image]

At 400mA you are looking at ~82% efficiency for 5V->12V. For the target 5W output, this means you are going to be dissipating around 1W in the IC.

Junction to ambient is given as 265C/W.  Without a top mounted heatsink (tricky on SOT23), the part is inevitably going to get hot.

This may be perfectly acceptable (see the part of the datasheet which details the thermal limits in the chip), but if you wish to lower the temperature, consider other ways to improve heatsinking.

Given the SOT23 package, the best way to decrease the package thermal impedance, is by increasing the PCB conductance.  Do this by increasing the size of the ground/power traces, have large ground/planes planes under the part and adjacent components (ideally including on the reverse of the PCB), and then stitch them together thermally with multiple vias.

This [app note](https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/powerhouse/posts/ldo-basics-thermals-how-hot-is-your-application) from TI gives good examples of how to maximize the thermal dissipation from SOT-23 packages.